# Conditionally use ADFS for login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, adfs

I have a requirement to integrate ADFS for one of our clients.

We're using OWIN and OAuth Bearer tokens, and JWT Bearer Auth. All of this works well. Put in a username (email) and password, authenticate against our database user store, get a bearer token.

We need to only ask the client's ADFS server for authentication when the username entered is in a specific domain - the client's. (We do not need to ask the password; the login has been modified to ask email first, check to see if it's a client domain, and then if not, then ask password - see how Box.com does it, that's very similar.)

We currently do not use AD at all and have no plants to do so, which means all of the "federate" examples that dot the web do not assist us in any way, because they assume you're already using ADFS or Azure AD, and we're not.

Our mobile app is using the ADAL 1.0 library, and works well to a point (it also needs #2 to work)

1) I can't figure out how to redirect the user's browser to the customer's ADFS login page. Everything uses a library, and all of those libraries are configured at compile time - whereas I don't know which client's ADFS to send the user to until that user actually starts the login process at run time. Also, this isn't using Azure AD, this is an on-premises server - so I can't use the Microsoft gateway.

2) The callback needs to parse the user's token, making sure it's meant for us, passes all the signing checks, and then we issue our own bearer token - we can't use the client's one. This should be relatively easy, but I don't know how to tell the ADFS endpoint what the callback URL is.

Yes I'm aware the reason these libraries were written is to make it harder to screw this up. I don't have much of a choice - these libraries want to take over the entire process, but I want to invoke them conditionally.

Some more information:

Client ADFS is 3.0

I have the ability to use OWIN's authentication for this, and could probably set up clients at compile-time if pressed.

Comment: I've worked with both On-Premesis WSFed based auth, and Azure AD auth. I gotta say, this is a very unusual use-case. 

Basically, your client is asking you to support their old on-premises tech. I'm not sure it can be done without writing your own authentication library. I definitely wouldn't depend on ADAL for this. 

At lease with Azure AD, you can configure for multi-tenant authentication, and this can be decided at runtime. I don't know that you can do the same for WSFed.

Worse still, WSFed is old tech, and in my experience it was really hard to find people who know enough.

Comment: They're using ADFS 3.0, so I might be able to at least speak SAML. Does that help?

Comment: You might be able to do it with some kind of middleware. There are companies out there that sell an SSO pipelines that support multiple scenarios.

This is how I did WSFed, although this won't work if you're using newer versions of the libraries mentioned here.

https://chris.59north.com/post/Manually-configuring-OWIN-WS-Federation-middleware-and-accepting-encrypted-tokens

Comment: Part of the problem here, is that ASP.net is assuming a single auth scenario. So when you issue a challenge to authenticate, it's going to forward you to whatever scenario has been configured at compile time. I don't know that you can accomplish what you need using the out of the box stuff.

For me, the client started with an On Premises AD solution, then moved to the cloud but maintained a hybrid environment. So we transitioned to Azure AD Authentication (using OpenIdConnect) at our convenience.

Comment: I'm sure I'm only muddying the waters here, but I'm going to follow. I'd be interested to see what a solution looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I'm sure I'm going to get some crap for this, but here goes.

We ended up using OAuth2 conditionally - examine the user's email address, look at the domain, and load the config info for their Single-Sign-On Experience.

I couldn't find any OAuth2 middleware for OWIN that I could invoke conditionally (the ADAL libraries didn't work even when I configured them with captions and in Passive mode), so I ended up redirecting to the IDP manually with the proper parameters. Our mobile developer is using ADAL 1.0 with Xamarin, so I was able to get the OAuth2 URL from that workflow (https://adfs.example.net/oauth2/authorize) and redirect there.

To solve step 1: I created an OAuth2 callback endpoint (which must be registered with ADFS! I have a querystring parameter that is a hint as to which SSO configuration to load, but that cannot vary at all - it must always be the same for that one IdP), and set up a method to swap the "code" query string parameter for the Token. This is a fairly straightforward HTTPS call, but you're going to have to both verify the token yourself (which is required for my requirement step 2) and have a bunch of code to dig out the email address / username claim. You must set up the grant types to transmit it, and be prepared to handle different namespaces of claims. Remember to pass your callback URL - the OAuth2 standard requires you pass it again, unchanged - or your code is invalid.

After verifying that the token was a valid token using the excellent `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` library (you will want to reference other questions on Stack Overflow about how to load X509 certificates in PEM format, as we wished to store the IDP's pubkey in ascii-armored PEM format in the database - code to fetch it was considered a nice-to-have at this time), AND was for the expected audience AND that the issuer was the one you expected (in case someone tries messing with the domain hints) AND that the signature matches (which catches most of these earlier cases), AND that it matched the email address that the user typed in (This is what the OWIN 'External Cookie' middleware does, when you can use it):

Then and only then you can issue a token.

I had to store a reference (we're using Autofac) to our JWT Protection Library in our Startup code:

`builder.RegisterInstance(customFormat).As<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>();`

ISecureDataFormat is what's registered to protect/unprotect JWT keys. I was not able to find a way to tap into the OWIN authentication object to find a way to find this instance as a property somewhere, so I had to store a reference to it in our IoC module.

Our login code (custom auth provider) looks something like this:

```
        var cookiesIdentity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, cookiesIdentity);

        // login
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", globalUser.UserName },
            { "userId", globalUser.Id.ToString() }
        })
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(28),
        };

        // jwt
        var oAuthIdentity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, "JWT");
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id.ToString()));
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email));
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, user.Contact.ContactFirstName + " " + user.Contact.ContactLastName));

        Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket at = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        string jwt = Startup.Resolve<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>().Protect(at);
```

The string 'jwt' is the actual raw authentication ticket, which we store in local storage to authenticate to the API. (Yes, our app is weird. You sign in to the MVC pages, but the pages call the API using a JWT token, the same way the mobile app does. It's not an SPA, but it sort of behaves like one.)

To solve step 2: The Microsoft ADAL library returns not the authorization code from the OAuth2 process, but the actual Token from the ADFS. I established another endpoint that starts the process in the middle of the step 1 solution, and calls the same methods to verify the token, extract the username/email, and return a bearer token. The ADAL library has already verified that the username input on the login form matches the claims in the token, but the server needs to verify the token is legit before exchanging it for our JWT bearer token.

I'm sure this could have been a lot easier, but to be honest with you, OAuth2 isn't too hard to do by hand - but only do this if you're forced. The OWIN middleware is well-tested and covers corner cases I get to spend the next month looking for - it just doesn't really support skipping a lot of steps.